# How to read and write text between two pattern matches

Tags: java

I am writing a code to read a text file and give output based on pattern 
matching.

For example, if "aa" comes in a file, it should start writing from there 
till it encounters another matched pattern "}}".

I have written a code which matches a pattern. but it only prints the  pattern that is being matched.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Reader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws          ParserConfigurationException,             SAXException, IOException {


    File xmlFile = new File("location.txt");
    Reader fileReader = new FileReader(xmlFile);
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = bufReader.readLine();
    while( line != null){
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
        line = bufReader.readLine();
    }
    String string = sb.toString();

    //System.out.println(string);

    int indexHello = string.lastIndexOf("aa");
    int indexBye = string.indexOf("}}", indexHello);
    String newString = string.substring(indexHello, indexBye+1);
    System.out.println(newString);}
    bufReader.close();

   }

         }
```

Expected result should be like

aa (all the content till it matches "}}")  .................}}

UPDATE: Somehow, I am able to read between "aa" and "}}". Now, my question is-  There are various occurrences of aa ....}} and I want to print all of them.

Comment: The easiest would be to read in the whole file, for example as List<String> or as single String, work with that and finally write everything back to the file. If this is feasible for your file sizes, that is.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Did you actually try to match the end pattern somehow? How? What did not work about it? For instance: You could try to match the line with the second pattern starting at the position of the start pattern you just found. Another possibility would be to put the start and end patterns in one regex with a placeholder inbetween.

Comment: Somehow, I am able to read between "aa" and "}}". Now, my question is-  There are various occurrences of aa ....}} and I want to print all of them.

Answer (score 0):

happy day. I hope what u want is this.

```
static String initiator = "aa";
static String finalizer = "}}";
static String target = "aa_Content_}}";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int statrtIndex = getContentStartIndex(initiator, target);
    int endIndex = getContentEndIndex(finalizer, target);
    String content = target.substring(statrtIndex, endIndex);
    System.out.println(content);
}

private static int getContentStartIndex(String initiator, String target) {
    return target.indexOf(initiator) + initiator.length();
}

private static int getContentEndIndex(String finalizer, String target) {
    return target.indexOf(finalizer);
}
```

if right, i'm happy. else, i'm sorry.
i'm not good at English. but i want to be help. :)

it print between aa, }}.

Answer (score 0):

```
                           import java.io.BufferedReader;
          import java.io.File;
          import java.io.FileReader;
           import java.io.IOException
              import java.io.Reader;
          import java.util.Scanner;
          import java.util.regex.Matcher;
          import java.util.regex.Pattern;

            import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

              import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


      public class XmlAsStringInJava {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {


    File xmlFile = new File("filelocation.txt");
    Reader fileReader = new FileReader(xmlFile);
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = bufReader.readLine();
    while( line != null){
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
        line = bufReader.readLine();
    }
    String string= sb.toString();
      bufReader.close();

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("aa(.+?)}}", Pattern.DOTALL);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println( matcher.group(0)); }

}
}
```